# Textmate-style snippets in Dreamweaver?

Tags: dreamweaver, code-snippets

Can anyone tell if Dreamweaver supports Code snippets/bundles in the same style as Textmate, Coda, and E-Text Editor?

That is, creating a 'trigger' in the form of a text string, followed by (usually) the Tab key.

I know it is possible to set up triggers using the 'Ctrl' key, followed by a letter or number.But this method is quite limited, plus many of these shortcuts are already being used.

What i want is to be able to type in  for example 'pagestart' + tab and it spits out my basic page structure snippet.

It would be great if it did. But I have a feeling it doens't

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a built in feature of Dreamweaver, but one of its built in features, extensibility, does allow for something similar to be done. There is an extension based on [Zen Coding](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/) that gets you part way there (see the [Downloads](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/downloads/list) page for the Dreamweaver extension). I don't know how easy it is to modify the code output for this extension, but if you snoop around in it's code I'm sure you could relatively easily add your own code chunks and tokens that get replaced.

Comment: Thanks Danilo. I discovered Zen Coding recently. But was unaware of a DW extension. Might give it a whirl!
If anyone out there is using it, I'd be niterested to hear your comments.